# Should questions about Q-learning solving in reinforcement learning be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

The following question:

- [How q-learning solves the issue with value iteration in model-free settings](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/2235/8)

sounds like a modelling question. Should it be on-topic?

Comment: I'd be interested to understand the thinking behind voting this question down.

Comment: On meta it's probably means 'no' to the question.